# Excel-VBA consecutive dots with regex

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to catch more than 2 consecutive dots in Excel with VBA. I am using the following regex: `"(\.{2,})"`

It seems to be correct if I try it for example here: https://regex101.com/

However Excel is giving me inconsistent results.

"." returns FALSE -> Correct

".." returns TRUE -> Correct

"…" returns FALSE -> Not correct

"…." returns FALSE -> Not correct

"….." returns TRUE -> Correct

(Just when I copy pasted it here, it seems like Excel is somehow merging 3 dots into 1)

Comment: I wonder if excel is automatically formatting three `.`'s to an ellipsis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so it looks like Excel by default replaces `...` with `…`. If you want to remove this auto correct you can by going into Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options (see below) and then just doing a find `…` replace `...`. Or you can just include `…` in your regex like this: `(…|\.{2,})`

[image: Capture]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Really easy to miss this. If I wouldn't have copied it out of the cell/you wouldn't have pointed it out what exactly it is, I never would've catched it. Unclear to me what the purpose of this autocorrect is tbh..

Comment: Single character ellipsis, allows the font to present it differently than just a normal consecutive three periods, generally more useful in word, but yes irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it works quite ok for me:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TryRegex(s As String) As Boolean

    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "(\.{2,})"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        Set inputMatches = .Execute(s)
        TryRegex = regEx.test(s)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print TryRegex(".")                       'False
    Debug.Print TryRegex("..")                      'True
    Debug.Print TryRegex("...")                     'True
    Debug.Print TryRegex("....")                    'True
    Debug.Print TryRegex(".I.live.in.submarine.")   'False
    Debug.Print TryRegex(".a.yellow.one..")         'True
End Sub
```

The code uses late binding, thus you do not need to reference any additional libraries.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically the exact code I was using, still didn't catch. Problem was as in accepted answer: Excel by default replaces "..." with "…". It's pretty confusing/hard to catch by eye depending on the font.

Comment: @Wehaga - you could have debugged in Regex101.com, the answer would have been visible quite quickly. :)